# react-simple-image-slider doesnt work on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have used react-simple-image-slider to build an image slider for my project. I fetch images from firestore and pass them in the slider properties. However, they dont show up the first time, but only if I re-render (not refresh). When I tried with hardcoded images it worked. Also, does anybody know how to make the background image fit into the slider? Thanks

Here is the code:

```
export const ProductPage = () => {

    const {uniqueProductName} = useParams();
    const [productImages, setProductImages] = React.useState([]);
    

    const fetchProduct=async()=>{
        const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("uniqueName", "==", uniqueProductName));
        const querySnapshot=await getDocs(q);
        let data = null;
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
            doc.data().img.forEach((image)=>{
                productImages.push({'url': image})
            })
            
        })

        setProductImages(productImages);
        console.log(productImages);
       


}

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(uniqueProductName);
        fetchProduct();
      });

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbarr/>
<MainContainer>
    <SliderContainer>
    <SimpleImageSlider
        width={896}
        height={504}
        images={productImages}
        showBullets={true}
        showNavs={true}
      />
</SliderContainer>
<InfoContainer>

</InfoContainer>
</MainContainer>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

For making the image background fit to slider, documentation says this, but I dont understand where to add it in my React app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9dXp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two main fixes:

```
const {uniqueProductName} = useParams();
const [productImages, setProductImages] = React.useState([]);
    

const fetchProduct = async () => {
        const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("uniqueName", "==", uniqueProductName));
        const querySnapshot=await getDocs(q);
        let data = null;
        // You need to use a new array to trigger a re-render since arrays are objects 
        // with a reference memory address, and when React compares them it makes a shallow 
        // compare, it just checks if they are the same object ( same reference ), 
        // not they have the same properties or elements.
        const imgs = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
            doc.data().img.forEach((image)=>{
                imgs.push({'url': image})
            })
            
        })

        setProductImages(imgs);       
}

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(uniqueProductName);
        fetchProduct();
      },[]);  // Add an empty array of deps, to make the fetch only on component mount, 
              // otherwise it will get stuck in a loop at each re-render.
```

Comment: can you please check my edit? maybe you know something about it?

Comment: Try to make another question, do not mix different questions in one!